# Get data from POSIX timezone files?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, timezone

IE: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 And looking at /usr/share/zoneinfo, But all the files seem to be written with binary, I would like to get the actual information from the file so any help is greatly appreciated.

(For more info):
I have the goal of taking time zone information / history and putting them into a relational database, So I believe learning how to do this might help with that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to retrieve this data from https://www.iana.org/time-zones ?

Comment: Yes I actually found this data but now when running ./Makefile i get a bunch of errors. Not quite sure what to do there. It says not too much configuration is need and that you may leave some variables empty but throws an error

Comment: The format has a man page: man -s 5 tzfile. You might need to write some C to extract it. Alternatively. you can od (octal dump) it in multiple formats and pick out the chars, ints and longs in awk. I can try that if you wish.

Comment: man tzfile notes the file it describes may not be authoritative: "It may only be in glibc just to support the non-glibc-maintained timezone data (which is maintained by some other entity)."

Comment: Related: [timezone: how to get the rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345464/timezone-how-to-get-the-rules)